# How to select sibling element(s) exclusive to the IntersectionObserver target(s)?

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

I have an `IntersectionObserver` for an `h2` that comes into view, and need to add/remove a class to the sibling of specifically that target `h2` which is `.preview-container`.

The markup is a list, and each item/container is `.project-list-item`. There are multiple of these, and I am intending to show the image *specific* to each.

**HTML**

```html
<div class="project-list-item">
  <h2>This is the title</h2>
  <div class="preview-container">
    <div class="image-container"><!-- Image --></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="project-list-item">
  <h2>This is another title</h2>
  <div class="preview-container">
    <div class="image-container"><!-- Other image --></div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- more -->
```

**JS v1**

```js
const projectListItem = document.querySelectorAll('.project-list-item h2');
const projectListPreview = projectListItem[0].querySelectorAll(+ '.preview-container');

const showPreview = new IntersectionObserver(
  entries => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        projectListPreview.forEach(previewSibling => {
          previewSibling.classList.add('preview-on');
          console.log('List item IN');
        })
      }
      else {
        projectListPreview.forEach(previewSibling => {
          previewSibling.classList.remove('preview-on');
          console.log('List item OUT');
        })
      }
    })
  },
  { rootMargin: "-40%" }
)
projectListItem.forEach(preview => {
  showPreview.observe(preview)
})
```

I'm trying to cycle through each of the `.preview-container`s as well, because there are multiple, but I am not sure if that is the best approach, because I technically need the *one* related to each target.

I tried a different method without `forEach()` and switching to `querySelector`, associating the target `const` with the sibling:

**JS v2**

```js
const projectListItem = document.querySelectorAll("project-list-item h2");
const projectListPreview = document.querySelector(CSS.escape(projectListItem) + '.preview-container');

const callback = (entries) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      projectListPreview.classList.add('preview-on');
      console.log('List item IN');
    } else {
      projectListPreview.classList.remove('preview-on');
      console.log('List item OUT');          
    }
    });
}    
const showPreview = new IntersectionObserver(callback, {rootMargin: "-30%"});    
projectListItem.forEach(preview => {
    showPreview.observe(preview);
});
```

I've managed to get it to where both of these methods produce no errors, but now nothing is happening, including no `console.log()`.

Could someone point out what I have missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every [IntersectionObserverEntry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserverEntry) exposes the element that is being observerd via the `target` property. From the observerd element you can use the [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling) property that gives you the element after the observed element, in this case being your `.preview-container` element.

```
const projectListItem = document.querySelectorAll('.project-list-item h2');
const projectListPreview = projectListItem[0].querySelectorAll(+ '.preview-container');

const showPreview = new IntersectionObserver(
  entries => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        entry.target.nextElementSibling.classList.add('preview-on');
        console.log('List item IN');
      }
      else {
        entry.target.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('preview-on');
        console.log('List item OUT');
      }
    })
  },
  { rootMargin: "-40%" }
);

projectListItem.forEach(preview => {
  showPreview.observe(preview)
})
```

Comment: Ah, you know, I was working with `nextElementSibling` but wrongfully when defining the variable. This works! One thing, and it's from my own mistake, the `else` should be `remove('preview-on')`, which I fixed in my post. Can you update that (I can't seem to edit yours) and I will mark as the answer. Thank you!